# How to manage git repository that contains projects with different release times?

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio

As is, I have a visual studio solution which contains multiple projects including a website, a desktop app, a library, and some periodic reporting applications. The git repository is at the solution level, so it covers all the projects. Now, I am actively working on a new, big part of the website, so there are many changes in the library and website. All these changes exist on their own. Likewise, all the changes for the desktop app exist on its own branch. When I want to release a new version of the website or the desktop app, I just build it from the respective branch. However, the library project has diverged a bit between the desktop app branch and the website branch.

So what's the better way to handle this? Should I merge the branches all into one? At this point, that would probably result in a huge amount of conflicts. Or should I be using different repositories for every project maybe?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for this problem.
Merging is not ideal as it will not solve the purpose.

Different Repo's looks the good way to move forward.

like

```
[yourPrjoectName]Desktop
[yourPrjoectName]Web
[yourPrjoectName]Common etc.
```

In this way you have different owner for different repos etc.